# ASP.NET how to call this stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure that I was provided:

```
USE [DatabaseName]
GO

DECLARE@return_value int,
@L1 nchar(10),
@L2 nchar(10),
@L3 nchar(10),
@L4 nchar(10),
@LD1 nchar(15),
@LD2 nchar(15),
@LD3 nchar(15),
@LD4 nchar(15)

EXEC@return_value = [dbo].[uspCheckTagId]
            @TagId = '10001',
            @deviceId = 'testunitid',
            @L1 = @L1 OUTPUT,
            @L2 = @L2 OUTPUT,
            @L3 = @L3 OUTPUT,
            @L4 = @L4 OUTPUT,
            @LD1 = @LD1 OUTPUT,
            @LD2 = @LD2 OUTPUT,
            @LD3 = @LD3 OUTPUT,
            @LD4 = @LD4 OUTPUT

SELECT
    @L1 as N'@L1',
    @L2 as N'@L2',
    @L3 as N'@L3',
    @L4 as N'@L4',
    @LD1 as N'@LD1',
    @LD2 as N'@LD2',
    @LD3 as N'@LD3',
    @LD4 as N'@LD4'

SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

My question is how would I call this stored procedure from ASP.NET?

I am completely starting from scratch so all the code I tried in the past is now gone :(

PLEASE HELP.

Comment: This is only parts of the stored procedure - please include the **full source** - and please also tell us **what concrete database** this is for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming** this is for **SQL Server** (you should *really* provide a proper tag for this!), you should use code something like this - put disposable things like `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` into proper `using(..) { ... }` blocks, use **parameters** for your procedure, etc.

```
procedure void CallStoredProcedure(int tagId)
{
    // get connection string, typically from config
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["...."].ConnectionString;

    // Define stored procedure name
    string storedProcedureName = "dbo.uspCheckTagId";

    // create connection and command
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmdExecProc = new SqlCommand(storedProcedureName, conn))
    {
        cmdExecProc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // build up parameters
        cmdExecProc.Parameters.Add("@TagId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = tagId;

        cmdExecProc.Parameters.Add("@L1", SqlDbType.NChar, 10).ParameterDirection = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmdExecProc.Parameters.Add("@L2", SqlDbType.NChar, 10).ParameterDirection = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmdExecProc.Parameters.Add("@L3", SqlDbType.NChar, 10).ParameterDirection = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmdExecProc.Parameters.Add("@L4", SqlDbType.NChar, 10).ParameterDirection = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmdExecProc.Parameters.Add("@LD1", SqlDbType.NChar, 15).ParameterDirection = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmdExecProc.Parameters.Add("@LD2", SqlDbType.NChar, 15).ParameterDirection = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmdExecProc.Parameters.Add("@LD3", SqlDbType.NChar, 15).ParameterDirection = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmdExecProc.Parameters.Add("@LD4", SqlDbType.NChar, 15).ParameterDirection = ParameterDirection.Output;

        // open connection, execute proc, close connection
        conn.Open();
        cmdExecProc.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // read out the output parameters here, and do with them whatever you need ......
        var l1Value = cmdExecProc.Parameters("@L1").Value;        
        ....

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would make the given procedure a stored procedure like the following:

```
CREATE PROC MyStoredProcedure
AS
<Code from your snipped without USE statement>
GO
```

Then i would call it from ASP.NET codebehind file

```
SqlConnection insSqlConnection = new SqlConnection("YOUR CONNECTION STRING HERE");
SqlCommand insSqlCommand = new SqlCommand("MyStoredProcedure", insSqlConnection);
insSqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlDataAdapter insSqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(insSqlCommand);
DataTable insDt = new DataTable();
insSqlDataAdapter.Fill(insDt);
insSqlConnection.Close();
```

If you can provide more details to your scenario there can be better ways of execution.

Comment: Since this procedure really isn't returning a result set - but only a few output parameters - using a `SqlDataAdapter` and a `DataTable` makes no sense at all ....